in building javascript bundle using vite how to make sure that fontawesome directives are included
In my vite/tailwind project i have following as part of safelist:
<script lang="ts">
safe_twsty_arr = ['bg-pink-500 ', 'fa-2x', 'fa-fw', 'fa-user', 'flex ', 'flex-col ', 'font-bold ', 'font-mono ', 'h-6 ', 'invisible ', 'justify-center ', 'md:w-1/3 ', 'mt-4 ', 'p-1 ', 'pb-2 ', 'pl-2 ', 'pt-2 ', 'sm:max-md:hidden ', 'sm:max-md:w-full ', 'space-x-8 ', 'space-y-2 ', 'svg-inline--fa', 'text-2xl ', 'w-6 '];
let concString = safe_twsty_arr.join(' ');



</script>

<div class={concString}></div>

<div class=''></div>

Have also installed @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0". But the resulting bundle and style.css does not contain any css for fontawesome directives like fa-2x, etc.

Is this your actual tailwind.config.cjs / .js?
Do you include the content directive? And you can use patterns for your safelist, by the way. Here is an example:
module.exports = {
    …
    content: [
        './your-directory-one-to-include/**/*.{ts,js,vue}',
        './your-directory-two-to-include/**/*.{ts,js,vue}',
    ],
    safelist: [
        { pattern: /opacity-(0|10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|90|100)/ },
        { pattern: /grid-rows-(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)/ }
    ],
    …
};


The problem is not tailwind classes. Its the fontawesome classes fa-2x, etc. For me tailwind was not picking up safelist, so this was the workaround.
